# Is moving files possible with Ubuntu/GNOME's Google Drive integration?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, permissions, google-drive

I have added a Google account to Ubuntu 18.04 and enabled the 'Files' sync as per [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/196635/an-official-google-drive-for-linux-is-here-sort-of-maybe-this-is-all-well-ever-get/).

I can see all my files and use them, however I today tried to move a file from one folder to another and received the message:

```
There was an error copying the file into google-drive://my@emailaddress.com/1izr... (long string of characters) Operation unsupported
```

Is this not permitted by Google or an issue with permissions or similar in Ubuntu?

It unfortunately makes the integration pretty worthless for my situation - I move files around quite a lot.

Also I have noticed deleting files will permanently delete them with no trace on Google Drive web version - is there a way to trash these instead or is this the only option?